# Find object in deep nested object by value

Tags: javascript

I would like to find an object `id` in deep nested object by value. I try to do it with recursion, but can't figure out why got 'undefined'.

In this code I have in console `"final result: 234324234"` which is correct, but for some reason this result is not returning from this function.

Please, take a look.

[demo in jsbin](https://jsbin.com/gadiwaluqu/1/edit?js,console)

```js
let obj = {
  "uuid": "344444",
  "entityName": "priceFormationPhase",
  "id": 2,
  "value": "foo",
  "children": {
    "4": {
      "uuid": "44444",
      "entityName": "organization",
      "id": 4,
      "value": "ffffff",
      "children": {
        "344534": {
          "uuid": "33333",
          "entityName": "contract",
          "id": 928688,
          "value": "dh",
          "children": {
            "345345": {
              "uuid": "222222222",
              "entityName": "contractPhase",
              "id": 234324234,
              "value": "111",
              "children": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function findContractStage(obj) {
  if ((typeof obj.children === 'object') && (Object.keys(obj.children).length > 0)) {
    findContractStage(obj.children);
  } else if (typeof obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]] === 'object') {
    findContractStage(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);
  } else if (obj.entityName) {
    console.log(`final result: ${obj.id}`);
    return obj.id;
  }

}

let contractStageId = findContractStage(obj);

console.log(`contractStageId: ${contractStageId}`);
```

Comment: You never `return` the result of the recursion, so your (first-level) function call never returns anything in that case.

Comment: @VLAZ that's true, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to `return` the function

```js
let obj = {
  "uuid": "344444",
  "entityName": "priceFormationPhase",
  "id": 2,
  "value": "foo",
  "children": {
    "4": {
      "uuid": "44444",
      "entityName": "organization",
      "id": 4,
      "value": "ffffff",
      "children": {
        "344534": {
          "uuid": "33333",
          "entityName": "contract",
          "id": 928688,
          "value": "dh",
          "children": {
            "345345": {
              "uuid": "222222222",
              "entityName": "contractPhase",
              "id": 234324234,
              "value": "111",
              "children": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function findContractStage(obj) {
  if ((typeof obj.children === 'object') && (Object.keys(obj.children).length > 0)) {
    return findContractStage(obj.children);
  } else if (typeof obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]] === 'object') {
    return findContractStage(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);
  } else if (obj.entityName) {
    console.log(`final result: ${obj.id}`);
    return obj.id;
  }

}

let contractStageId = findContractStage(obj);

console.log(`contractStageId: ${contractStageId}`);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I'll up rate your answer tomorrow when I'll have new rate points.

Comment: No worries, please :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning the value you get when you recurse. Try this:

```js
let obj = {


"uuid": "344444",
  "entityName": "priceFormationPhase",
  "id": 2,
  "value": "foo",
  "children": {
    "4": {
      "uuid": "44444",
      "entityName": "organization",
      "id": 4,
      "value": "ffffff",
      "children": {
        "344534": {
          "uuid": "33333",
          "entityName": "contract",
          "id": 928688,
          "value": "dh",
          "children": {
            "345345": {
              "uuid": "222222222",
              "entityName": "contractPhase",
              "id": 234324234,
              "value": "111",
              "children": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function findContractStage(obj) {
        if ((typeof obj.children === 'object') && (Object.keys(obj.children).length > 0)) {
          return findContractStage(obj.children);
        } else if (typeof obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]] === 'object') {
          return findContractStage(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);
        } else if (obj.entityName) {
          console.log(`final result: ${obj.id}`);
          return obj.id;
        }

      }

  let contractStageId = findContractStage(obj);

  console.log(`contractStageId: ${contractStageId}`);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll up rate your answer tomorrow when I'll have new rate points.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "return" before recursive calls

`return findContractStage(obj.children);`

and

`return findContractStage(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);`

So your recursive function goes deeper as it can and return your id value.